# Cannot get Alexa to use dialog model

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have been building my interaction model with the new skill builder (beta), and according to the document, I should be able to use the dialog model. I tried to test the intent and the JSON does not include `dialogState` like what is said on the document. Anyone know how to enable dialog model?

Comment: Note that it's in beta, unexpected things may happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the exact same problem. Apparently, the dialogState property isn't included in the request when you test via the Dashboard UI. You need to use the device itself. So testing locally or via the dashboard will make it seem like there is a bug that isn't actually there. [This thread](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/68046/skill-builder-required-slot-alexa-does-not-ask-que.html) helped a lot.